# Why is the following jQuery selector not returning both elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I've run into a situation where I am creating a jQuery object from an html string and need to select all elements within it with a particular class.

What I'm finding odd is that its returning one or the other, depending on which type of selecting mechanism I'm using. A test case is shown here:

```
var tmpl = '<ul><li class="foo">TEST</li></ul><div class="foo">BAR</div>';

console.log( $('.foo', tmpl) ); //[<li class="foo">TEST</li>]
console.log( $(tmpl).find('.foo') ); //[<li class="foo">TEST</li>]
console.log( $(tmpl).filter('.foo') ); //[<div class="foo">BAR</div>]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rfq9F/

In this example, both an li element in a ul and a non-descendant div have the class "foo". In the example, I use the .foo selector and set context to the template string. Second, I use .find() on the string. Finally, I use .filter() on the string.

Can someone explain why the selector mechanisms are acting as they do, and also how to achieve the goal I mentioned in the beginning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because it's not a single root node, but two (`ul` and `div`).

Wrap everything in a `<div>` and it will work:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rfq9F/3/

Answer (score 2):

Calling `$(tmpl)` creates a set with two elements - the `<ul>` element and the `<div class="foo">` element. `.find()` looks for elements that are descendents of any of the elements in the set that match the selector. `.filter()` returns any elements in the set that match the selector.

The first two lines:

```
console.log( $('.foo', tmpl) );
console.log( $(tmpl).find('.foo') );
```

are equivalent, they're just two different ways to write the same thing.